# Range of domain on monic polynomials bounded by 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am asked to show that if $p$ is a monic polynomial of degree n≥1 such that for all $x\in[a,b]$ we have that $|p(x)|\leq 2$ then it must be that $b-a\leq 4$.This seems intuitive, but highly difficult. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: One observation: The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind seem to show that the number $4$ is tight.

Comment: That was excellent. You just need to know what is the norm of the monic polynomial with the least norm, which is everywhere on the web.